# Rental Agent claiming an admin fee from 2 years ago

Tags: contract-law, united-kingdom, rental-property

(Context Details: UK, renting in London. Agent is Foxtons.)

I've just left a rental property after 3 years there.
The landlord has authorised the full return of the deposit, but the rental agency has turned around and said that there's £96 of annual renewal fees outstanding.

I've proved that I paid the fee 1 year ago, and I have several emails from them discussing the "outstanding balance" from the points at which the monthly rent changed, but they're now asserting that the outstanding fee is from 2 years ago, and that those conversations were about the RENTAL balance only (and thus don't pertain to any administration fee balance).

As far as I can tell they are technically right - there's an email from 2 years ago asserting that they WILL invoice me for the renewal, but no actual INVOICE for that (that I received) and it looks like all the payments I made add up to cover the rent and NOT the renewal fee.

So I think their assertions about what happened are correct.

Question: Am I actually obligated to pay this fee?
If they didn't invoice me CAN they turn around 2 years later and say "we should totally have charged you for this." The Ts&Cs do state that there will be such a fee.

Comment: Before anyone suggests it ...  alas, they have a clause that allows them to deduct outstanding fees from the deposit, so I can't just walk away and tell them to sue me for it if they're certain.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the contract, you must pay it. You can claim money up to the statute of limitations which will almost certainly be more than 2 years.

Comment: You are correct,it is 6 years from my understanding.
Unless there is something in law which specifically tenders to his circumstances.